# Which folder should the bower.js file be in inside of a VS 2015 web project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bower

I'm playing around with an Angular site that uses bower. To get things to work inside of VS 2015 web project, I created a wwwroot folder and moved the app folder into it.

So now my folder structure looks like this:

```
MyWebsite\  
   MyWebsite.sln
   bower.json
   gruntfile.js
   node_modules\
   bower_components\
   wwwroot\
      app\
         bower_components\
         ... (all my other Angular files)
```

I think the bower_components folder is now duplicated but I'm not really sure which one should be removed (and if I do, where should the bower.json be)?

Comment: did you try renaming `root\bower_components` to `root\der` to test your understanding? Is there a bower.json in the wwwroot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would put everything INSIDE the  (relative to) `www-root`. Images in `www-root/images`, javascript in `www-root/js`, and so on. Or even inside `www-root/app`.